# Laravel Mail::To() does not send email but works on Mail::Send()

Tags: laravel, email, smtp, phpmailer, mailgun

```
public function sample(){
      // USER SUBSCRIPTION
      $Subscriber = Subscriber::find(100021);
      $email = 'jakeromeopeniano@gmail.com';
      Mail::to($email)->send(new Subscribed($Subscriber));

      if(Mail::failures()){
          return Mail::failures();
      }

      return 'email sent to ' . $email;
  }
```

I'm very much confused. I just switched my domain host, and now I'm having issues with my emails. But I'm sure that I've already setup the correct details in my env. If I use the mail::send() function, the email successfully sends in mailgun. But if I use the mail::to() function, I don't receive any errors but the email is not being sent. I also checked the logs, there's also no errors. Here's my code:

[My sample function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe2vW.png)

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\Subscriber;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class Subscribed extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $subscriber;
    public $password;

    public $tries = 2;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Subscriber $subscriber, $password = "****")
    {
        $this->subscriber = $subscriber;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $subscription = $this->subscriber->subscription;
        $subscriber = $this->subscriber;
        $password = $this->password;
        return $this->markdown('emails.subscription.subscribed', compact('subscriber', 'password'))
                    ->subject($subscription->name . ' subscribed successfully.');
    }
}
```

[Subscriber.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVu6K.png)

Comment: have you checked if there's a port blocked in your host? If mailgun is working, it means there's nothing wrong with the programming logic behind (at first sight, of course), check your connections to the smtp server.

Comment: @DanielaC.Montenegro I'm sorry if this is a weird question but as I mentioned in the question, the email sends successfully if I use laravel's mail::send() function. The trouble comes if I use my original code which posted in the question mail::to().

Comment: It could be a problem with the facade call, then... check [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/method-to-not-found-in-illuminatesupportfacadesmail), they used \Mail::send instead.

Comment: Please do not SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and SHOUTING will not get you an answer any faster. It's also rather impolite to come here and SHOUT while asking for *free help* to solve **your** problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel stupid, I forgot to configure my queue workers in ploi.